# What design pattern is this? Object that converts from byte[] to own type and back

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm working on desktop software that works with embedded device.

On desktop I created classes like this:

```
// This is C# code

public class ThermostatConfigEntry
{
    public sbyte TempSetting { get; set; }
    public byte HistSetting { get; set; }
    public byte RelayOutputMask { get; set; }
    public byte SensorFailureOutputMask { get; set; }

    // (...) constructors
    // (...) public methods
}
```

For communication between desktop application and embedded device I'm using Modbus protocol that supports 1-bit (boolean) and 16-bit (unsigned short) data types.

So to create instance of this object from data received from Modbus with constructor:

```
    public ThermostatConfigEntry(byte id, ushort[] data)
    {
        byte s = 0;
        ushort temp;

        temp = data[s++];
        TempSetting = temp.HighSByte();
        HistSetting = temp.LowByte();

        temp = data[s++];
        RelayOutputMask = temp.HighByte();
        SensorFailureOutputMask = temp.LowByte();
    }
```

To send this object via Modbus I have created `ToUShortArray()` methods:

```
    public ushort[] ToUShortArray()
    {
        return new ushort[] {
            Helpers.FromBytes(TempSetting, HistSetting),
            Helpers.FromBytes(RelayOutputMask, SensorFailureOutputMask)
        };
    }
```

Complete class looks like this:

```
public class ThermostatConfigEntry : IModbusMappableObject
{
    public sbyte TempSetting { get; set; }
    public byte HistSetting { get; set; }
    public byte RelayOutputMask { get; set; }
    public byte SensorFailureOutputMask { get; set; }

    public ThermostatConfigEntry(ushort[] data)
    {
        byte s = 0;
        ushort temp;

        temp = data[s++];
        TempSetting = temp.HighSByte();
        HistSetting = temp.LowByte();

        temp = data[s++];
        RelayOutputMask = temp.HighByte();
        SensorFailureOutputMask = temp.LowByte();
    }

    public override ushort[] ToUShortArray()
    {
        return new ushort[] {
            Helpers.FromBytes(TempSetting, HistSetting),
            Helpers.FromBytes(RelayOutputMask, SensorFailureOutputMask)
        };
    }
}
```

So, this is POCO + constructor that takes array + method that returns array.

I have many classes like this.

**Question:**

- I don't know how to call these objects and where to put them in my project structure. Is there some design pattern or some name for classes like this?

I guess is not enough logic for DAO (Data Access Object), not DTO (Data Transfer Object), too much for POCO (Plain Old CLR Object).

Comment: These are DTO's, but as you note it's more common to seperate the parsing/serialzing logic from the DTO into a sepreate class, or embed it in a service or repository type.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The API he is using enforces the use of a custom DTO with modbus conversion interop, deriving from _IModbusMappableObject_. So I can understand why he wants to put serialisation into the DTO.

Comment: And I don't think it's a bad practice in any case.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions guys. `IModbusMappableObject` is my interface which I'm using to standarize these objects. There is just ToUShortArray() and I want to add CreateFromUShortArray() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you are using stimulates the use of specific classes for each entity that is convertible to a modbus word array. I would call this type of classes **Domain Classes**. They are part of the domain of the API you are using.

They make sense at a low level, but I would map them to DTO's or your own POCO's with more appropriate types when using them in applications.

Modbus Domain Class

> ```
> public class ThermostatConfigEntry : IModbusMappableObject
> {
>     public sbyte TempSetting { get; set; }
>     public byte HistSetting { get; set; }
>     public byte RelayOutputMask { get; set; }
>     public byte SensorFailureOutputMask { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Your POCO Class

```
public class ThermostatConfigurationItem
{
    public TemperatureSettingKind TempSetting { get; set; }
    public HistorySettingKind HistSetting { get; set; }
    public RelayOutputs RelayOutputMask { get; set; }
    public SensorFailures SensorFailureOutputMask { get; set; }
}

public TemperatureSettingKind : sbyte
{
    None = 0,
    Centigrade,
    Fahrenheit
}

// and so on ..
```

One other thing I would like to address is this constructor:

> ```
>  public ThermostatConfigEntry(ushort[] data)
>  {
>     // ..
>  }
> ```

This is not very usable when parsing modbus entries from a stream of data. Consider using a method instead with a ref cursor for advancing the stream.

```
 public void ReadFrom(ushort[] data, ref int position)
 {
    // ..
    position += 4; // or whatever
 }
```

Edit:

I also noticed this:

> ```
>    TempSetting = temp.HighSByte();
>    HistSetting = temp.LowByte();
> ```

Do realise that modbus allows all kinds of endianness. Your implementation might be to strict.

Comment: Thank you for opinion. For clarity - I'm not parsing Modbus streams myself, I'm using NModbus4 library that does all low level things and gives me array of short. And TempSetting is temperature in Celsius, HistSetting is histeresis in Celsius/10 for clarity. I like your approach with TemperatureSettingKind where I can define unit, because my embedded device uses multiplier in some fields to make better use of 8-bit data type (eg. hysteresis range is from -10 to +10, so it is stored in 1/10 degree units in single byte.

Comment: `Do realise that modbus allows all kinds of endianness. Your implementation might be to strict.` This application purpose is to handle just my Modbus device where I have fixed endianess.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using  kinda of converter.It can be your constructors too.
Then your constructor can get byte array and convert it to your class type.